# Javascript, how to convert varying Date formats to a common format

Tags: javascript, date, timezone

I have several sources for date data that include a date and a time. There are several different formats (all are string) that are returned from either an api or a page scrape. It seemed to me that using GMT as a base and Date.parse on the front end to convert to local time for the UI would work. I have however encountered a data source that is returning the date in the format:

"02/15/2019 2 AM EST"

I am now reconsidering my date architecture and whether GMT is the best options. All source date/times will be North American.

I am trying to understand if there is any date library or methods that will handle the "2 AM EST" part or if I will have to do the conversion myself (rolling the date back as well). It's not making sense to me at this time to convert EST to GMT just to convert it back to EST on the front end.

Any advice?

Comment: For storage, the number returned by `myDate.getTime()` is quite convenient, and it could help avoid this worry.  As to parsing several different formats, will you face the common issue of whether `05/03` represents the fifth day of March or the third day of May?  If so, you're going to need some additional context in your parsing.

Comment: As of this moment I do not have a problem with 03/03/2019 (I picked a fine day to work on date formats). Thanks, I'll take a look at myDate.getTime().

Comment: Thanks, I don't think getTime is going to help. I have "2 AM EST" which isn't going to work for input to getTime(). That's the real issue. Getting "2 AM EST" into a format for GMT is the issue, since it is really the day before at 9 PM.

Answer (score 2):

The first part, `02/15/2019 2 AM` can be parsed with libraries like [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/), [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/), or [Date-fns](https://date-fns.org/).

However, one *cannot* parse time zone abbreviations on a global scale.  The canonical example is the abbreviation `CST`, which can be interpreted as US Central Standard Time, Australia Central Standard Time, China Standard Time or Cuba Standard Time.  Many other ambiguities exist as well.

Therefore, only when you already know all of the abbreviations you will encounter and how you want to interpret them, can you map an abbreviation to a time zone offset.  For example, if you only care about time in the continental US, then you can map the following:

```
EDT = -4
EST = -5
CDT = -5
CST = -6
MDT = -6
MST = -7
PDT = -7
PST = -8
```

But then if you want to add in Alaska and Hawaii, you might need to add:

```
AKDT = -8
AKST = -9
HADT = -9
HAST = -10
HST = -10
```

Note how both `HST` and `HAST` are used for Hawaii?  Both are commonly used there.  Even if you decide you want `HST`, you still need `HAST` and `HADT` for the Aleutian Islands in Alaska - which are in a separate time zone than the rest of Alaska.

And what about other US Territories, does your data include them?

You can see how things can get quite complicated.  In general, time zone abbreviations shouldn't be parsed, but instead just used for display to human beings.  If you are producing data that needs later interpretation, the data should include a time zone offset instead.

Comment: I am not producing time zones, only consuming. Thanks. The issue with converting time zones is dates, not the time. Subtracting 5 hrs from 2 AM.

Comment: Well, where so you consume them *from*?  How reliable is the data, and do you have enough data to know the entire list of abbreviations you might receive?

Comment: Also, one cannot separate the date from the time in this process.  You must convert them together.

Comment: Just noticed you gave some of this in your question, "... that are returned from either an api or a page scrape...".  In the case of an API, that API should give you the time zone offset.  If it only gives you an abbreviation, then they are doing it wrong and you should go yell at them.  In the case of a page scrape - sorry, but there is no foolproof solution.  The abbreviation could be anything at all, and there's no way to know.  But more than that, you have the problem of not knowing if a date like `1/2/2019` means "January 2nd 2019" or "February 1st 2019".  They will vary by locale.